# routing in laravel with xampp

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I have started to learn laravel, (I am quite a beginner). While I was going through auth tutorial, I faced following behaviour which I don't understand.

I can access all parts of my project using Url

`localhost/myproject/public/laravel_route`
(I am using XAMPP)

when i submit a form at `localhost/myproject/public/auth/register`

with  `target = 'auth/register'` and `method='post'` it tends to go to

`localhost/myproject/public/auth/auth/register`

Please Explain

Comment: try to add backslash with target, like this...  /auth/register

Comment: Thanks Qazi, I have already tried that, it takes me to `localhost/auth/register`

Comment: Welcome, try to read and understand routes and its usage. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `url()` function in blade file

```
<form action={{url('auth/register')}} method ='post'>
```